# Currency converter in Python 2.7

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, json

I'm a beginner and it is my first project in Python 2.7.

My goal is writing a script that I can run with two or three arguments.
If run with two arguments like `python currency.py RUB USD` then the output will be current RUB rate by USD base: .015169.
If run with three arguments like `python currency.py 1000 RUB USD` then it will convert 1000 RUB to dollar.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ast, requests
import sys, argparse
def checker(base, symbol):
    url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=%s" % base.upper()
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = ast.literal_eval(r.content)
    rate = content["rates"][symbol.upper()]
    return rate
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Currency converter. For instance : 'Convert 100 USD to RUB' Will be: 100 USD RUB. If You need only rate: USD RUB")
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    parser.add_argument("n", type =int, help = "Amount of currency_for_convert", default=1)
parser.add_argument('currency_for_convert', type=str, help="Currency for convert")
parser.add_argument("currency_converted_to", type=str, help = "Currency that converted to")
args = parser.parse_args()
rate = checker(args.currency_for_convert, args.currency_converted_to)
print rate if len(sys.argv) <= 3 else rate*args.n
```

But I don't like the way I'm using if statements because the running script help ignore third argument and give information only about first two arguments.

> $ python currency.py --help usage: currency.py [-h]
>   currency_for_convert currency_converted_to
>
> Currency converter. For instance : 'Convert 100 USD to RUB' Will be:
>   100 USD RUB. If You need only rate: USD RUB
>
> positional arguments:   currency_for_convert   Currency for convert
>   currency_converted_to  Currency that converted to
>
> optional arguments:   -h, --help            show this help message and
>   exit

Is there another way to write two/tree arguments script?

Comment: Your spelling of "currency" is inconsistent (i.e. wrong) in several places.

Comment: Reading your question, it sounds like your Python script isn't working properly (since *help ignore third argument*). If so, it is off-topic for Code Review since this site expects working code.

Comment: @Tunaki I believe they mean that the command line help isn't very clear because of the way their parameters work, not that it's nonfunctional.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan It is functional , but the --help option does not give whole information about arguments. I could use "n" argument as optional. In this case, I should type "-n" every time I give the third argument that makes input more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never assume that your user doesn't make mistakes.  I ran your program with no arguments ... error message, fine.  I ran it with a single argument of `4` ... error message, fine.  I ran it with two arguments, `4` and `5` ...:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    rate = checker(args.curency_for_convert, args.curency_converted_to)
  File "test.py", line 9, in checker
    rate = content["rates"][symbol.upper()]
KeyError: 'rates'
```

For debugging purposes, I put `print content` above that line and ran again:

```
{'error': 'Invalid base'}
```

If I run the program with a valid base, but an invalid symbol:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    rate = checker(args.curency_for_convert, args.curency_converted_to)
  File "test.py", line 8, in checker
    rate = content["rates"][symbol.upper()]
KeyError: '8'
```

You should catch these errors and display something that is a little more user-friendly.

---

I would recommend that you read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.  There are a couple things you aren't following:

> Imports should usually be on separate lines, e.g.:
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> import os
> import sys
> ```
>
> No:
>
> ```
> import sys, os
> ```
>
> It's okay to say this though:
>
> ```
> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
> ```

---

> Don't use spaces around the `=` sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

---

Your whitespace is a little strange.  I would have at least one blank line above and below the function definition.  I would also put one after the `if` block and maybe even before it too.  You have " =", " = ", and "=" used in just three lines.  PEP 8 says that [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds), but that doesn't mean never be consistent.  It is only the foolish consitency which is a hobgoblin.  In this case, you have nothing to lose.

Your naming is a little strange.  `n` even shows up in the `help` messages.  One-letter variable names are generally not recommended because they give very little idea of what the variable is for.  `curency_for_convert` and `curency_converted_to`, besides mis-spelling "currency", are ungrammatical.  You could say "for conversion" or "to convert", but "for convert"?  I would suggest "convert_from" and "convert_to".

> ```
> if len(sys.argv) > 3:
>     parser.add_argument("n", type =int, help = "Amount of curency_for_convert", default=1)
> ```

Instead of manually parsing an argument, make it optional with `nargs='?'`

> ```
> print rate if len(sys.argv) <= 3 else rate*args.n
> ```

Since our argument will always be present (either with the default of `1` or with a user-supplied number), we can now do `print rate * args.n`.

### Full Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import ast
import requests
import sys

def checker(base, symbol):
    url = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=%s" % base.upper()
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = ast.literal_eval(r.content)
    rate = content["rates"][symbol.upper()]
    return rate

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=
    "Currency converter. For instance: to convert 100 USD to RUB, it would be "
    "100 USD RUB. If you need only the rate: USD RUB"
)

parser.add_argument("amount", type=int, help="Amount of currency to convert", default=1, nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('convert_from', type=str, help="Currency to convert")
parser.add_argument('convert_to', type=str, help = "Currency of converted")

args = parser.parse_args()

try:
    rate = checker(args.convert_from, args.convert_to)
except KeyError:
    print "Invalid argument(s)"
else:
    print rate*args.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

## Style

Give your program some love. As it stand it is just a big pile of instructions. Add a bit of vertical spacing to separate logical sections, limit your line length so we can get most things at a glance.

You should also read and follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python's style guide:

- each import statement on its own line;
- consistent use of spaces around the `=` sign;
- meaningful variable names (`r` is not).

The `url` variable isn't really one. You should extract it out of the function and give it a proper capitalized name as the constant it is. Also you should use `str.format` instead of `%` as [it is the new standard](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

## Top-level code

Even if it is not that important for such "short" code, it is always a good practice to wrap your top-level code under an [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) statement. At the very least, it lets you `import` your code into an interactive session to test your function without triggering all its logic.

## Requests

The responses from `api.fixer.io` are json strings, not Python dictionaries. You can convert back and forth between the two using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json). However, `requests` provide a builtin hook for that so you don't even have to import the module:

```
content = r.json()
```

## Argparse

You can totally get the help usage you’re looking for if you provide more than two parameters to your program. For instance:

```
$ python currency.py a b --help
```

However it is less than ideal. Argparse provide a way to have optional required arguments (sounds weird anyway):

- set the `nargs` parameter to `'?'` to indicate it is optional;
- set a `default` value.

Since there is only one optional parameter, `argparse` will figure out things pretty well base on the length of `sys.argv`. Now how do **you** figure it out? Easily enough, if `default=1` then you perform `rate * args.n` blindlessly.

Oh, and `type=str` is useless as it is the default.

## Proposed improvements

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import argparse


URL = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?base={}"


def get_rate(base, symbol):
    url = URL.format(base.upper())
    content = requests.get(url).json()
    return content['rates'][symbol.upper()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description="Currency converter. For instance : 'Convert 100"
            " USD to RUB' Will be: 100 USD RUB. If You need only rate: "
            "USD RUB")
    parser.add_argument("n", type=int, nargs="?", default=1,
                        help="Amount of currency_for_convert")
    parser.add_argument("base_currency", help="Currency for convert")
    parser.add_argument("converted_currency", help="Currency that converted to")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    converted = args.n * get_rate(args.base_currency, args.converted_currency)
    print converted
```

You may also be interested into handling [networking issues](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions), [conversions issues](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) or [bad currencies](http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=FOO).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I found your answer very useful and informative!